# How do I make a download link open in a new browser tab when clicked and set a countdown on that tab before the file download link appears

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, download

Hello coders in the house.
I am a complete beginner, I saw something on `thewpclub.Net` and I want to implement the same on my `Wordpress` blog.

When someone clicks a download link, I want a new browser tab to open and display a countdown timer like 15 seconds before the main download link will now appear.

Pls try and download from thewpclub. Net , you will understand what am trying to say.

What I have tried:

A friend on facebook gave me this jquery code.

But after I paste it in my blog.
The countdown just happens right away on the same post page. It doesn't even wait for user to click the link not to talk of opening a new tab.

See the code below

```js
function c() {
    var startTime = $('.c').attr('id');
    var counter = startTime;
    $('.c').text(counter);

    setInterval(function() {
        counter--;

        if (counter > 0) {
            $('.c').text(counter);
        }
        // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
        if (counter === 0) {
            // alert('this is where it happens');
            clearInterval(counter);
            $('.c').text('');
            $('.c').append('<a href="#">Download</a>');
        }
    }, 1000);
}
// Start
c();
```

```html
<span class="c" id="5"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

--------- Updated Answer based on first comment -------

You have to create 2 separate html files. The first HTML (first_page.html) file contains the link for opening the page which contains the download link in a new tab.

Here is what first_page.html looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>First Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href="second_page.html" id="pseudo-dynamism" target="_blank">Click to open download page</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

The second HTML page (second_page.html) contains the code to create the counter and display the download link when the counter expires. The important point to note is that I am using [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to execute this code when this page loads.

Here is the second_page.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head> 
  <body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
  function c() {
   var startTime = $('.c').attr('id');
   var counter = startTime;
   $('.c').text(counter);

            setInterval(function() {
    counter--;

    if (counter > 0) {
     $('.c').text(counter);
    }
    // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
    if (counter === 0) {
     // alert('this is where it happens');
     clearInterval(counter);
     $('.c').text('');
     $('.c').append('<a href="#">Download</a>');
    }
   }, 1000);
  }
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    c();
  });
 </script>
 <span class="c" id="5"></span>
  </body>
</html>
  </body>
</html>
```

This should now meet your expectations. Hope it helps!

--------- Original Answer--------------

You can open a new tab on clicking a link by specifying `target="_blank"` property in your `<a>` tag.

```html
<a href="http://example.com" id="pseudo-dynamism" target="_blank">Click</a>
```

On this page, you can then display the counter before display the download link.

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks @hardik tewari.  I understand that target="_blank" will make a link open in a new tab. But how do i make countdown to happen on that new tab before the download link will finally display. Pls check thewpclub. Net. Any download link you click on that website will automatically open in a dynamic page thewpclub. Net/download and a 15 seconds countdown will happen before the main download link appear. I want to do the same. I want every download link on howtechwork.com when clicked to open howtechwork.com/download in a new tab and do a countdown of 15 second before the download link appear

Comment: @Mayheptad, I have updated my answer based on my new understanding of the requirements. Please let me know if it meets your expectations.

Comment: Thanks you very much@hardik tewari.  I understand ur code perfectly and it work. But my problem now is that i want to do this same thing for many download links from many post on my blog.  If i understand ur code very well after the coutdown on the new tab the content of $('.c').append('<a href="#">Download</a>');  will be appended to the html span tag. Now Is there anyway i can make the href value to change to whatever file link i want. For example blogpost A is "yoast plugin freedownload" and at the end of the post i provide a link which will open on secondpage.html in new tab when clicked

Comment: And after the countdown on secondpage.html expires it will now display the link. Now blogpost B is "newspaper theme freedownload" and at the end of the post i provide a link to the theme which i want it to open in secondpage.html and append the newpaper theme download link to the span tag on secondpage. Html.  Hope u understand me now.  So i want to know how possible it is to change the download link in the href tag which the jquery code will append on the second page. Html. Sometin tells me this is not possible in javascript maybe thewpclub.net is using a php script to do this